# Azure AD redirect to "/code" after login angular

Tags: angular, authentication, redirect, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

After connecting to AZURE AD, I am redirected to: http://localhost:4200/#code= refresh_token_value

I specify the route /code: HomeComponent but doesn't work.

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. Like how you setup your MSAL config (interceptors, etc) and routes.

Comment: and What is the complete redirect url provided in app registration in portal ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.